# Retrieve array from SQLite in listview with more than a colum (ANDROID)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

So I want to create a listview that consists of more than a column. I already succeed called the database, **but the layouting still not work. I think this is because the all my data are put in one array and its difficult to make  them in three columns. anyone can find solution for me?**

My program result is like this in listview:

```
John Doe     12   Argentina
Marilyn Rose  32  Russia
Annabella  19  United States
```

However what I want is more like this:

```
John Doe        12      Argentina
Marilyn Rose    32      Russia
Annabella       19      United States
```

From what I read, we will need 2 XMLs. One for listview, and another is for layouting (give space between text). And One .JAVA called adapter to connect my MainActivity.java and layouting XML.

**add:
I already tried using two XMLs. one XML, lets call it main.XML is for calling ListView. And grid.XML, is where i put android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" (to create spaces).
I used MyAdapter.JAVA  to convertview in grid.XML. and in MainActivity.JAVA i called MyAdapter. However my code in MainActivity became error when its connected it MyAdapter.**

*this was my code that gave error java.lang.RuntimeException. So I had to delete it.. more information about it, please check two last code...*

**MainActivity.java (error)**

```
public static ArrayList<String> arraydealer = new ArrayList<String>(); 
MyAdapter bohwat = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraydealer);   
lvcustom.setAdapter(bohwat);
```

And here is the code that is working well. It uses class MainActivity, AstraDB, and MySetGet, and main.XML. Other class thats not working is MyAdapter and grid.xml

This is how I called my database:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static ArrayList<String> arraydealer = new ArrayList<String>();
    AstraDB astrahandler = new AstraDB(this);
    Spinner spDealer;
    ListView lvcustom;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lvcustom = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_lv);
        ShowListView();
    }

private void ShowListView()
{
        astrahandler.getAllDealer();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraydealer);
        lvcustom.setAdapter(adapt);
}
}
```

**This code of ArrayList in Activity and String name in AstraDB are very important to connect my MainActivity with the database but it seems this create trouble in layouting. because they are contained in ONE array**

And this is function to get all data in my DB. its on AstraDB.java:

```
public List<MySetGet> getAllDealer()
        {
            List<MySetGet> info = new ArrayList<MySetGet>();

            db = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Dealer";

            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    MySetGet lets = new MySetGet();
                    lets.setDealerID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    lets.setDealerName(cursor.getString(1));
                    lets.setDealerOwner(cursor.getString(2));
                    lets.setDealerWil(cursor.getString(3));

                    String name = cursor.getInt(0) +
                            "\u00A0 "+ cursor.getString(1)+ 
                            "\u00A0 "+ cursor.getString(2)+ 
                            "\u00A0 "+ cursor.getString(3);


                    MainActivity.arraydealer.add(name);
                    //add
                    info.add(lets);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            //return contentdealer;
            return info;
        }
```

The MySetGet in getAllDealer() connects with MySetGet.java where I put setter and getter so the data can become object. which is more like this:

```
public int getDealerID(){ return DealerID;}
public void setDealerID(int DealerID) { this.DealerID = DealerID; }
```

Code to connect other XML with Java but still gave error:

**grid_dealer.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/col1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text=""/>

                <TextView 
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/col2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/col1"                
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text=""/>
```

important code in MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<MySetGet> dealerlist;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MySetGet>list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        dealerlist = list;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MySetGet yay = dealerlist.get(position);

        //this is to customize the layout of the listview
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_dealer, null);
        }

        TextView tvID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.col1);
        tvID.setText(yay.getDealerID());

        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.col2);
        tvName.setText(yay.getDealerName());

        TextView tvOwner = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.col3);
        tvOwner.setText(yay.getDealerOwner());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Please help me. I am very new to this. Is there a way to modify my code without changing too much on how I called my database? The class and XML below works fine in showing database, but didnt create a neat layout space between columns
*Working class : AstraDB, MainActivity, MySetGet
Working XML : main.xml*
Im sorry, if the post becomes longer. I want to clarify several things so that there is no misunderstanding.

Comment: If you have more number of tables like this, you can think about some ORM tools like ormlite http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Comment: Since you are new to this, you can refer to this url http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html

Comment: Try using custom layout.

Comment: @Vinothkumar Arputharaj , thank you. I already used the tutorial for reference. All I want now is to make neat column space, but my code gave error when i try to connect 2 XMLs..

Comment: you can follow @Aniruddha suggestion

Comment: I think change layout will not work for me, I already tried. It is because I put all database rows into one array... Any suggestion for that? I tried to put the one row in three columns but eclipse didnt recognize when I put: String name = cursor.getString(0), String age = cursor.getInt(1). I want to add them into this, but unsuccessfull : MainActivity.arraydealer.add(name, age);

Answer (score 1):

you can use `android:layout_weight=""` for better arrangement of views

Comment: umm, i think the major problem is not in XML.. thank you, i will give addition in my post

Comment: if u want to customize `listview` row, then you will need to modify ur `AdapterActivity` and `XML` file

Comment: I already modified adapter, but it gave error so I had to removed it. do u know where i did wrong?   
I already put the error code above

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I just added android:layout_weight="1" in my xml file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it doesnt work for me because I put all database rows into one array... Any suggestion for that? I tried to put the one row in three columns but eclipse didnt recognize when I put: String name = cursor.getString(0), String age = cursor.getInt(1). I want to add them into this, but unsuccessfull : MainActivity.arraydealer.add(name, age);

Answer (score 0):

Using [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is the ideal solution in your case. Please checkout a tutorial [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) that will take you through the steps in achieving what you want.

Comment: thank you. i am going to try it... i'll tell you how it turns @Rajesh

Comment: well, I already read but still confused.. is the tutorial using URI for layouting?
if I use URI intead, will a class of URI able to handle several xmls that show database with many columns? Thank you for reply

Comment: You could do without the `ContentResolver` and directly use the `Cursor` you got from the `DBHelper`.

Comment: Is ContentResolver the same as URI? Well I am trying.. I think it doesnt work for me because I put all database rows into one array... Any suggestion for that? I tried to put the one row in three columns but eclipse didnt recognize when I put: String name = cursor.getString(0), String age = cursor.getInt(1). I want to add them into this, but unsuccessfull : MainActivity.arraydealer.add(name, age);

Comment: Using a `Cursor` is different from storing everything to an array. You iterate a `Cursor` to get what you want as against referencing an index. Please get yourself a book - you could find a list of books or reference materials in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info.

Answer (score 0):

In `simple_list_item_1` layout if you arrange items relative to each other you will get the result what you are getting now. If you want proper formatting, relate the elements to left, center and right using `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` respectively

Comment: I already tried it in two XMLs. one XML, lets call it main.XML is for calling ListView. And grid.XML, is where i put the code you gave. But it still gave error. I already put the code above. Do you know where I got wrong? Thank you